# How to run a method on multiple days during a duration on those days?

Tags: java, timer, timertask

Is there a way in Java to run a specific method based on a set of days at specific times?

Say for example I have the following days:

13-11-2015 to 15-11-2015

And time is between 11AM to 6PM.

So I want a method to run only on those days at those times.

I'm aware of the timer task but I don't think there is a way to set up multiple days right and only at those times? After these timings I want it to stop or run in the background and not do anything until those dates are updated.

I should have mentioned I can't use Quartz due to project specifications. Is there any other way or is this not possible?

Comment: So you are looking for something like a cron scheduler in Java? If so, Quartz comes to mind - https://quartz-scheduler.org/overview

Comment: You didn't give any constraints so I'll offer up Spring's solution @Scheduled which takes a cron-like string which should be able to do what you ask.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [Quartz Scheduler](https://quartz-scheduler.org/) for this. It allows you to schedule a task to run at an interval (in miliseconds) or on a predefined date and time (for as long as specified) based on a `CRON` expression.

You can find the documentation for this here:
https://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation

**EDIT In response to the updated question:**

If `Quartz` isn't an option, there is a long, comprehensive list of alternatives at java-source.net on *"Open Source Job Schedulers in Java"* :

http://java-source.net/open-source/job-schedulers

Comment: I can't use Quartz unfortunately, I've updated the question to reflect this restriction. :(

Comment: That's a shame! Is your software running as a service, or just a program that will remain open for that period of time?

Comment: I've updated my answer to give a list of alternatives! :)

Comment: The scheduler is on a Java server that runs as a Spring application. The input for the times is fetched from a website application that someone enters when they need to run this service

Answer (score 2):

You might also take a look at the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) Interface.

Comment: Indeed, these built-in classes are easy to use and work well. Your Runnable/Callable could check the current date-time and skip its work if not yet time.

Comment: @Basil Bourque Can you give an example on how this would be achieved please?